# Always show my inline styles in intellij idea html editor (and not "...")

Tags: html, intellij-idea

Intellij shows my inline `style` attributes as ellipsis, for example :

```
<table id="my-id" style="...">
```

When I click on the ellipsis, it shows the whole style, but I would like to see my inline styles all the time. How do I do that...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**IntelliJ IDEA 15 & 16**

File > Settings ... > Editor > General > Code Folding > uncheck HTML 'style' attribute

[image]

[image]